# why don't work buttons in GNOME Videos (Totem)

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, video-player, media-buttons

After install nvidia drivers 304.131 or 361.42 from -Software & Updates>Additional Drivers-. I have to say  It was working before with Nouveau.
when I do click above the buttons they do nothing.
I only can use the keyboard, e.g. for pause I use p key or space bar.

Additional drivers:
[image]

Totem:
[image]

```
Pc especifications:
motherboard: intel DH87RL
memory: 15.5GiB
processor: intel core i5-4430 3.00GHz x4
os type: 64-bit Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
graphics: GeForce GT 610/PCIe/SSE2
driver: Nvidia legacy binary driver-version 304.131
```

Comment: what do you suggest we can do?, thanks in advance

Comment: Hi christianbueno.1, did you find a definitive solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**how we can solve this?**
You have to test more nvidia drivers, all you have on hand.
As in my case none worked I had to install this ppa for more drivers "graphics-drivers/ppa". More information [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html).

*Open your terminal:*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

After that you can test more drivers, for example the 367.44 and check if it works. In my case this solve my problem.
[Software & Update image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hqdyc2pj33ne5zb/Screenshot%20from%202016-09-30%2011-24-22.png?raw=1)